# OpenCV with Microsoft Kinect SDK (C++)

Tags: opencv, kinect

Can anyone share how to use OpenCV with C++ SkeletalViewer sample ?

I am using OpenCV2.3 with with SkeletalViewer sample. However, I got the following errors while trying to create an image using cvCreateImage();

**error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvCreateImage  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Microsoft Research KinectSDK Samples\NUI\SkeletalViewer - Copy\CPP\NuiImpl.obj    SkeletalViewer
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Public\Documents\Microsoft Research KinectSDK Samples\NUI\SkeletalViewer - Copy\CPP\Debug\SkeletalViewer.exe   SkeletalViewer**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't added the library to your project. Right-click your project and go to Properties. Then go to Linker >> General >> Additional Library Directories, set this to 
**"$(YOUR_OPENCV_ROOT)\lib"**. Next, go to Linker >> Input >> Additional Dependencies and make sure **opencv_core230.lib** (or opencv_core231.lib, which ever 2.3.x version you are using) is in there.

Also, I would highly suggest using the C++ interface as it has more functionality than the C interface especially in OpenCV 2.3.x.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I created a new vs2010 project with this library setting and it works. However, I tried to set this library in the Kinect SkeletalViewer sample and it still has the errors I mentioned above.